# Expression Builder for a command Button in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am new to MS Access and would like to work with buttons of a form. I wanted to understand a point

I have a text box search and I have a button in the form

I don't want to use VBA and with the help of Expression Builder can I clear the Text in Text Box search after clicking the button?

I have tried and it isn't working out. Is it the right way ?

Comment: What did you try? A macro? Use SetValue method in macro. Expression Builder is not needed.

Comment: In other words, must be VBA or macro. Expression Builder is not relevant.

Comment: @June7 - I have zero understanding in VBA. So was trying that out with Expression builder but seems like it wouldn't work without a VBA right ?

Comment: I said macro is alternative to VBA.

Comment: technically you can do this in the Expression Builder by calling a public function you write in vba that has the side effect of clearing the textbox.  But why?  in the button afterUpdate event, just add  me.mytextboxesname = ""

Answer (score 1):

With expression builder you can only call a user function, macro or vba routine.
Try with vba code:

```
Me.controlName.value = ""
```

**Me** is your form.

**controlName** is the name of your field (in my [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prJqc.png) is "**txt_somefield**")

Click on button, Event, Onclick and put this code (remember to replace your field's name).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to use Expression Builder. A simple macro will do the trick.

Select `Properties` of Command Button, under `Events` choose `...` next to `On Click`and then `Macro Builder`

Add Action, choose your TextBox control name, select `Set Property`, then `Value` - and leave Value blank

[image: Set Property Macro]

Save and Exit and Run